# async & await - dealing with multiple calls to same method - locking/waiting on each other?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I had a complex Task/lock based mess for performing a 'long' data operation, and I'm trying to replace it with an async/await. I'm new to async await, so I'm worried I'm making some big mistakes.

To simplify things, my UI has a few pages that depend on the same data. Now, I only need to get this data once. So I cache it, and further calls just grab it from the cache "CachedDataObjects" rather than doing the long call every time.

Like this (semi-pseudocode):

```
    private Dictionary<Guid,List<Data>> CachedDataObjects;

    public async Task<List<Data>> GetData(Guid ID)
    {
        List<Data> data = null;

        //see if we have any cached
        CachedDataObjects.TryGetValue(ID, out data);

        if (data == null)
        {
            if (ConnectedToServer)
            {
                data = new List<Data>();
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //long data call
                        data = Service.GetKPI(ID);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //deal with errors (passes an action to do if resolved)
                        PromptForConnection(new Task(async () => { data = await GetData(ID); }), e);
                    }
                });
            }

            CachedDataObjects.Add(ID, data);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

However, by the nature of the asynchronous calls, this method get's called by the two pages when they are triggered.

As a result, there's an exception - an item with the ID has already been added to the dictionary. Even if I patched that problem, the underlying issue is still there. The Data objects would be different versions, I'm doing two network calls where I should only have one etc.

Previously, I 'hacked' a solution by encapsulating the whole method in a lock statement - thereby only allowing a single call to it. All my data loading being done in background workers, the first did the call, and once it had finished the others were then unlocked to perform the quick grab.

But I can't use lock in an asynchronous method, and the solution didn't feel good anyway.

Is there any way with asynchronous methods to 'wait' on other asynchronous calls to finish?

Comment: in this case caching make sense ?

Comment: @PankajGupta sorry, slight error in code. "CachedDataObjects" now used throughout as the dictionary.

Comment: ,sorry didn't get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're `await`ing the task before adding it to the dictionary. In this case, you'll want to add the *task* to the dictionary, so that the next page calling this method will get the same *task:*

```
public Task<List<Data>> GetData(Guid ID)
{
  Task<List<Data>> task = null;
  CachedDataObjects.TryGetValue(ID, out task);
  if (task == null)
  {
    if (ConnectedToServer)
    {
      task = Task.Run(() =>
      {
        try
        {
          //long data call
          return Service.GetKPI(ID);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          //deal with errors
        }
      });
    }
    DataObjects.Add(ID, task);
  }
  return task;
}
```

This will cache the *task*. However, if `//deal with errors` propagates exceptions, then this will cache that exception as well.

To avoid this, you can use more complex code, or you can adopt my [`AsyncLazy<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination):

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, AsyncLazy<List<Data>>> CachedDataObjects;
public Task<List<Data>> GetData(Guid ID)
{
  var lazy = CachedDataObjects.GetOrAdd(ID, id =>
      new AsyncLazy<List<Data>>(() => Task.Run(() =>
      {
        try
        {
          return Service.GetKPI(ID);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          //deal with errors
          throw;
        }
      }, AsyncLazyFlags.RetryOnFailure | AsyncLazyFlags.ExecuteOnCallingThread)));
  return lazy.Task;
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, to cache the task instead of the result. As far as I can see, there would still be need for a lock in order to consistently avoid race conditions between cache test and assignment?

Comment: @grek40: If you are using a non-concurrent dictionary and are accessing this method from multiple threads, then yes, a lock would be required.

Comment: That's a great idea!

Comment: Got both methods working, but thought I'd use AsyncLazy, as it seems neater. Still getting my head around it though.

Comment: @StephenCleary I am getting this error "anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value" Any ide how to get around of this?

Comment: @HaBo: I don't think the code in my answer would cause that error. Please post your own question with the specific code.

Comment: @StephenCleary here is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64993808/asynclazy-anonymous-function-converted-to-a-void-returning-delegate-cannot-retur