# AsyncLazy anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, lazy-loading

I am trying to call a ASP.NET MVC Action Result concurrently 11 times which is throwing few errors. To address that found a solution for  similar issue poster over here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38636016/942855

Followed same answer using https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLazy

Here is my code

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<GcrModelFull, 
            AsyncLazy<List<Airport>>> CachedProximityAirports;

        public Task<List<Airport>> GcrAsync(GcrModelFull model)
        {
            var lazy = CachedProximityAirports.GetOrAdd(model, x =>
                    new AsyncLazy<List<Airport>>(() => Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            return MyGcr(x.DepartureTimeOffset, x.Legs,
                                x.DepartureTimezoneInfo, x.OperatingUser, x.RequestEntity);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            //deal with errors
                            throw;
                        }
                    }, AsyncLazyFlags.RetryOnFailure | AsyncLazyFlags.ExecuteOnCallingThread)));
            return lazy.Task;
        }
```

I am using ASp.NET MVC on .NET CORE and [Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/)

Its complaining on my return

> Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot
> return a value

Internal calling method signature is as below

```
 private Task<List<Airport>> MyGcr(DateTimeOffset departureTimeOffset, List<RouteLeg> legs,
            TimeZoneInfo departureTimezoneInfo,
            User operatingUser, string requestEntity)
        {
             // some code
             return Task.FromResult(listOfAirportData);
        }
```

---

Update:
It is still an issue if I replace

```
return MyGcr(x.DepartureTimeOffset, x.Legs,
                                    x.DepartureTimezoneInfo, x.OperatingUser, x.RequestEntity);
```

with

```
return null;
```

So internal calling method has no impact on this error.

---

Update:
Comment from @stephen helped to resolve the compile time issues, but main problem still exists. Want to call this method 11 time at a time asynchronously from JS
[image]

Any help on how to overcome this error is appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to use `AsyncLazy<Task<T>>`; use `AsyncLazy<T>` instead.

Comment: @StephenCleary Still same no difference . Here is the screen shot https://ibb.co/sPnCTLF

Comment: @StephenCleary Was able to make it work by removing TASK. But that did not fix my main problem, having to a call same method 11 times asynchronously from JS. That still breaks